# Confusion between strips, discs and shells

Tags: calculus

My syllabus indicates I must be able to find mean values and centroids of 2 and 3 dimensional figures (equations in cartesian coordinates) using strips, discs and shells as appropriate.

However, I don't know which method (strips, discs and shell method) is which, and I can't seem to find relevant methods on the internet. Could someone explain with little detail each method, and if possible, explain the strips method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard of the strips method. Maybe I know it by another name.

Disks (aka Washers) is a method based on cutting a solid into flat disks (washers is the solid has a middle part hollowed out). These cuts go perpendicular to the axis of revolution. The general formula is as follows:
$$\int_a^b \pi [f(x)]^2 dx$$
where your curve is $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$. This further generalises if we have an inner ($g$) and outer ($f$) curve:
$$\int_a^b \pi [f(x)]^2 -[g(x)]^2dx$$

These are for a horizontal axis (like the $x$-axis). There are variants further on this depending on what your axis is.

Shells is a method that uses thin shells to find a volume. The classic example is those Russian nesting dolls. The shells are hollow cylinders that have center axis the axis of revolution. The basic formula is as follows:
$$\int_a^b 2\pi x [f(x)] dx$$
This would correspond to a vertical axis of revolution (like the $y$-axis).

Comment: Doesn't that second formula need an $x$?

Comment: I have edited it. Good catch.